# Unable to read values from property file using @value or by using Autowired to Enviroment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, dependency-injection

I have two properties file in my Spring boot project. And I am able to read the properties from both in one class. But the same value when I am trying to read from a different class using @Value or by Autowired Environment, it is giving me null.

```
    prop.name=test /*   property file value */

    @Component
    public class TestUtil { // This is the class giving me null value

        @Value("${prop.name}")
        String st;

        public String getTestString()
        {
            System.out.println(st+ " ***");
            return st;

        }
    }

//Using @Autowired Enviroment
public class TestUtil {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    public String getTestString()
    {
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("prop.name")+ " ***");
        return env.getProperty("prop.name");

    }
}

/* Class below giving me value from properties file*/

        public class JsonWriter extends JsonResponseWriter {

        @Value("${prop.name}")
        private String contentsMenus;

      /* Some method*/
       System.err.println("from JsonWriter  "+contentsMenus);
```

Here I am autowiring

```
@Service
public class ResponseUtil {
    @Autowired
     private TestUtil util ;
```

In the above class I am using autowired

Comment: Let me guess you do `new TestUtil()` and expect the value to be filled, instead of using a spring managed instance of `TestUtil`.

Comment: Tried both Autowiring and creating object using new.

Comment: Autowiring should work, if that doesn't work your setup is borked as an `@Value` simply will never be `null` (unless provided as a default). If a property cannot be resolved your application simply won't start. Hence I still think you are doing a `new TestUtil` instead of using the spring managed instance.

Comment: But let me surprise you the project is running and the property is resolving if you go through my question, I can access the property value from a different class.

Comment: As stated you are either using `new TestUtil` or haven't setup property resolution correctly. I suspect the first... However you aren't showing where you are using `TestUtil` (and the fact that is a util makes me wonder if you mayne forgot a `static` keyword in your question). Also your edit with the `@Autowired` doesn't have an `@Component` which in turn makes `@Autowired` useless, unless you have an `@Bean` method creating the instance.

Comment: I have edited the question and provide the piece of code

Comment: That is only a class definition it doesn't show the usage of the `TestUtil`. The fact that you have `@Autowired` doesn't mean you mistakenly have a `new TestUtil` somewhere in  your code. Again Spring doesn't allow an `@Value` to be unresolved, it will simply blow up.. There is no gray area in there. Hence the issue is in your usage of the class.

Comment: You must use @Component above TestUtil class. Otherwise spring will never inject that class.

Comment: Error Resolved I have Answered the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After M. Deinum comments analyzed the code and found that the first class from where I was calling another class was not autowired.So after autowiring the class it worked. Thanks a lot @M.Deinum and all the users who answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a dollar sign in `Value` annotation. This should do the work:

```
@Value("${prop.name}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but no use tried the same, Just a note It's working in another class which I have and I am getting the value of prop.name

Comment: Are you importing it from spring instead of, for example, lombok?

Answer (score 1):

use $ in property names: E.g.:

```
@Value("${prop.name}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that piece of code

```
@Component
public class TestUtil {

@Autowired
private Environment env;


  public String getTestString(){
    System.out.println(env.getProperty("prop.name")+ " ***");
    return env.getProperty("prop.name");

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Σωτήρης Ραφαήλ but it's not working. I am getting value using both ways in another class that I have 

public class JsonWriter extends JsonResponseWriter {

 @Value("${prop.name}")
 private String contentsMenus;
And it's working fine

Comment: Should you try to set the String of the example you pasted here to private?

Comment: In your other class which that code works do you have a setter method as well?

Comment: No,  in the class in which it's working doesn't have a setter method

Comment: I tested the code which gives you null value and it works as expected.

Comment: That's what the problem is the same piece of code is working in my another class I have edited the question and I have provided the code of the other class which is working fine but when I am trying to do the same in TestUtil is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191840/discussion-between-aman-vyas-and--).